# Understanding an argument about a union forming the set of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The excellent book Transition into Advanced mathematics states the following:

The union of the family $$ \{ (-x,x):x\in R\ and\ x>0 \}$$ is the set of all real numbers because every real number `b` is an element of the open interval $$ (-|b| - 1, |b| + 1) $$

I assume that their explanation is meant to imply an obvious proof (of this obvious fact) but I cannot think of a way to actually construct a proof. How did they get to the +1 / -1 argument and how does it help me prove that the union of the aforementioned sets is the set of real numbers?

Comment: There is no special significance to the number $1$ here. The author chould equally well have picked $(-|b|-2,|b|+2)$ or $(-|b|-\frac12,|b|+\frac12)$ or $(-|b|-\pi,|b|+\pi)$ to use in the proof.

Comment: @HenningMakholm this is for me **the** key thing, I was thinking about the one too much - the argument is (hopefully) about showing that for each b assumed to be in reals, we can construct an interval into which it belongs and that interval is guaranteed to be in the set

Answer (score 0):

Since $0<1$ and $b\le|b|$, we have
$$
b<|b|+1
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Is it correcct reasoning to say that since every open interval is in the set, then picking an arbitrary $$b \in R$$, we can also pick an arbitrary positive real number $$k \in R$$ (which happens to be 1 in the book) and then the interval $$(-|b| -k, |b| +k)$$ must also be in the set (from definition) and contain `b` itself (from your argument) - and as such we can conclude that since we assumed nothing about `b`, it follows that every `b` is in R?

Comment: @AntlerM No, it's not true that every open interval is in the set.

Comment: Every open interval symmetric around 0 :), naturally

Comment: @AntlerM That's right, but doesn't help in the proof. Given $b\in\mathbb{R}$ you have to show there is $x>0$ such that $b\in(-x,x)$. There are several ways to do it; one is with $|b|+1$; you can show, instead, that $-2|b|<b<2|b|$.

Comment: It felt unnatural to me because we are doing unions of sets where all but one up to some k are irrelevant as they are subsets of the **(-k, k)** one. I was thinking how to exploit this fact that if we union a set with its subset, we still get the original set. This property does not seem useful (here) though.

Comment: @egreg: $2|b|$ will not work for $b=0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, right; on the other hand it should be an easy separate case.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is, if a specific real, say $\alpha$ is in 
$$ A_x=\{ (-x,x):x\in R\ \text {and}\ x>0 \}$$
then take the interval $\alpha \in (-\mid \alpha \mid-1, \mid\alpha \mid+1)\subset \bigcup_xA_x$. So, $\alpha$ is in the big union.

As far as the $\pm$ argument. How would you construct an interval (symmetrical around  $0$ if it was requested that $\alpha$ be in it. Is it not natural for a positive alpha to take a positive number $\varepsilon$ and say that the interval $$(-\alpha-\varepsilon,\alpha +\varepsilon)$$

would do it? if $\alpha<0$ the you would do the same with $\mid\alpha \mid.$ $\varepsilon=1$ is an accidental choice.

Comment: The arbitrarity of the 1 is the key thing for me :). Also the reasoning that is along the lines of "by picking an arbitrary b and showing P(b), we can say that forall b, P(b)".